# How i can filter all the info open?

Tags: django

There are 2 models

```
class info(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class state(models.Model):
    shopkeeper = models.ForeignKey(info)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=False)
    date_register = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

There are the records on DB. How can I get all the info objects who  last Status is Open. For example in image they will be  only 85,84,81,82. The id 85 and 79 is not returned in the query because they have a last register on Close

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

info.objects.annotate(
    last_value=Subquery(state.objects.filter(
        shopkeeper_id=OuterRef('pk')
    ).order_by('-date_register').values('state')[:1])
).filter(last_value='Open')
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`info`</s> to `Info`.